# OSX-like ('finder') File Manager for Linux / Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, file-management, ubuntu

I am looking for a stable and production ready file manager / file explorer for (Ubuntu) Linux, which has a similar approach on UI and directory browsing as the standard Finder application on Mac OSX computers. 
Any recommandations anybody?

Comment: What is wrong with the default file manager of Ubuntu?

Comment: IDK about Finder but [Dolphin](https://www.kde.org/applications/system/dolphin/) is one of the finest and [feature-rich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolphin_(file_manager)#Features) file explorer available for GNU/Linux.

Comment: @Cornelius, Ubuntu's default file manager ('nautilus') mimics the behaviour of Windows Explorer. The user interface concept is different to the concept of OSX finder. It's simply a matter of personal preferences, which concept you like more...

Comment: @Firelord Dolphin is quite similar to nautilus in terms of file browsing and user interface concept in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Try Pantheon

It's the file explorer bundled in Elementary OS. The graphic interface is clearly inspired by the OSX Finder so I believe it's what you're looking for.

[image: pantheon]

### Installation

#### Add the elementary repo

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable
```

#### Update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

#### Install

```
sudo apt-get install pantheon-files
```

#### Add-ons (optional)

```
sudo apt-get install pantheon-files-plugin-ubuntuone pantheon-files-plugin-dropbox
```

## Or Thunar

In my opinion, Pantheon looks very much like a prettier version of Thunar (from XFCE) which you might want to check out as a lightweight alternative.

[image: thunar]

### Installation

```
sudo apt-get install thunar
```

Comment: I hit a lot of unmet dependencies when I followed your instructions on Ubuntu 14. After trying to get Elementary to install I think it isn't compatible. Thunar installed easily.

Comment: If you're using Elementary, Pantheon is actually already installed.

Comment: 'Unable to locate package pantheon-files' I got this error even through added the repo

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different options but out of all of the ones I am telling you, I like Dolphin best.

Here is the list of alternatives to Finder for Ubuntu:

1. Dolphin File Manager
2. Files
3. Double Commander

Dolphin File Manager is available in KDE Discover

Files is available in GNOME Software or KDE Discover

Double Commander is available in GNOME Software or KDE Discover

Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you please explain why you recommend Dolphin.  That would make a much better answer.