# Mac-like file browser for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, file-management, ubuntu

Navigating the folders and sub folders all in the same window like in the screenshot below.

[image: Mac OS X file manager, showing the folder hierarchy in three columns]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OSX-like ('finder') File Manager for Linux / Ubuntu?](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19835/osx-like-finder-file-manager-for-linux-ubuntu)

Comment: Check out Elementary OS' file browser, sometimes called Pantheon. I've tried it several times but found it a bit unstable and buggy occasionally